# How to generate a connection string that contains logged in user id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How can I get logged in user id in Data Context class?
The user id is always null because the DbContext constructor executing before authentication pipeline

I need to set the connection string according to user id. How can I do that?

```
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

        public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(options)
        {
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string userId = "";
            if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                userId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            }
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer($"my connection string;userid={userId}");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you maybe need a semicolon before that userid?

Comment: That connectionString variable is empty, is that just to not share real details?

Comment: It's not important. the issue is: getting user id in this method.

Comment: *DbContext constructor executing before authentication pipeline* -- So what exactly is the authentication flow? You're not going to allow unauthenticated people to query your database. You always need a userId.